# Is there a performance boost by using yield with foreach?

Tags: c#, foreach

After reading a few articles : 
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

There is one thing that I didn't quite understand and was curious about.

I was curious to know a foreach loop can utilize yielded function's results before all the yields have been completed.

Take the follow functions for example:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> RandomFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            yield return i; 
    }

    public static void PrintRandomResult1()
    {
        foreach (var i in RandomFunction())
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    public static void PrintRandomResult2()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> Enumerable = RandomFunction();
        foreach(var i in Enumerable)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

If we use PrintRandomResult2 I would assume the Randomfunction would have reached all of its yields before the foreach beings; however, if we call the RandomFunction directly in the foreach will the iterations begin before RandomFunction is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was curious to know a foreach loop can utilize yielded function's results before all the yields have been completed.

Absolutely, that's part of the point. The iterator block executes lazily.

The method effectively "pauses" when it hits a `yield return` - then continues next time the `foreach` loop implicitly calls `MoveNext()`. It *doesn't* just run through the whole code and build up a list to return at the end, if that's what you were speculating.

From the MSDN page you linked to:

> When a `yield return` statement is reached in the iterator method, *expression* is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.

EDIT: You've linked to my implementation article - the [more introductory article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) might help you, as that gives a worked example.

Comment: I did read it >< but I'm a little new to this and I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: @Aelphaeis: It does take a little while to get your head round. If you edit your `RandomFunction` to print when it's about to yield, you'll be able to see that output interleaved with the output from the calling code.

Comment: Another question that this begs is since the foreach loop becomes expanded on by the compiler is it better to use a for loop most of the time and only use the foreach loop when the functionality of the foreach loop is absolutely necessary?

Comment: @Aelphaeis What advantage(s) are you expecting to get from using a `for` loop?

Comment: @Aelphaeis: A `foreach` loop is *more readable* than a `for` loop usually, and with at least *little* impact on performance. (Sometimes it may be faster, sometimes it may be a little slower - it really depends on what you're iterating over.) You should usually code for simplicitly first, and measure performance to see where you need to micro-optimize.

Comment: Well, the advantages would depend on the context of its usage I think (And I'm really just asking for the clarification); however, there seems to be overhead associated with using the foreach loop, so in cases where you are doing simple wouldn't you get performance out of a for loop?

Comment: @Aelphaeis: You might get a tiny bit of a performance boost, but it wouldn't be significant in most cases. The readability benefit *is* significant in my view.

Comment: @JonSkeet I had written that before I read your comment, sorry about that. Thank you for the clarification though.

Comment: excellent article jon loved it .thanks. but I want to ask one thing its second time i saw compiler generated code somewhere, earlier i saw a piece of it in article where it was showed how compiler generates code for async and await , and both of these places i saw the use of goto statement . Though it is always recommended to avoid goto

Comment: @ethicallogics: You should avoid `goto` in *your own source code* - but that's because it makes code hard to read. You don't need to read the code that the compiler generates for you.

Answer (score 3):

Jon has answered the explicit question, but the question implied in the title is about a "performance boost".  In regard to this, you should bear in mind that the iterator is likely to give you the *first* result more quickly than 'do everything and then return' loop, but is likely to give you the *last* result more slowly.

Whether or not you see this as a 'boost' is rather context-dependent.